# MySQL query returning 0 rows while it should return one

Tags: mysql, sql

Something is wrong with my MySQL query below but I can't find the problem. It's not returning any errors but the query below should return 1 row, but it returns none.

The table 'fws_product' contains all products. The table 'webits_product_has_kenmerken' contains the product specifications.

```
SELECT fws_product.* 
FROM webits_product_has_kenmerken 
LEFT JOIN fws_product ON webits_product_has_kenmerken.product_id = fws_product.ID 
WHERE fws_product.CATID = 11 
AND ( 
(webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_id = 8 AND webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_value = 'Buddha to Buddha') 
AND
(webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_id = 19 AND webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_value = '10 mm')
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that 3rd `AND` shouldn't be `OR`?

Comment: That indeed returns results, but I wan't to get the products wich match both specifications and not just one of the two. It's an query for the product filter.

Comment: oh...okay, next time specify that in the question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit nasty, but the following should do as you have requested

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM fws_product AS p

INNER JOIN webits_product_has_kenmerken AS ps8 
    ON ps8.product_id = p.ID
    AND ps8.kenmerk_id = 8
    AND ps8.kenmark_value = 'Buddha to Buddha'

INNER JOIN webits_product_has_kenmerken AS ps19 
    ON ps19.product_id = p.ID
    AND ps19.kenmerk_id = 19
    AND ps19.kenmark_value = '10 mm'

WHERE p.CATID = 11
```

This is another potential option which may do the job, but still feels very nasty

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM fws_product AS p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        COUNT(*) AS numMatches
    FROM webits_product_has_kenmerken
    WHERE (kenmerk_id,kenmerk_value) IN (
            (8,'Buddha to Buddha'),
            (19,'10 mm')
        )
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING numMatches = 2
) AS ps
ON ps.product_id = p.ID

WHERE p.CATID = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the following:

```
SELECT fws_product.* 
FROM webits_product_has_kenmerken 
LEFT JOIN fws_product ON webits_product_has_kenmerken.product_id = fws_product.ID 
WHERE fws_product.CATID = 11 
AND ( 
(webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_id = 8 AND webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_value = 'Buddha to Buddha') 
OR
(webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_id = 19 AND webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_value = '10 mm')
)
```

Comment: That indeed returns results, but I wan't to get the products wich match both specifications and not just one of the two. It's an query for the product filter.

Answer (score 0):

checke these columns for NULL values:

```
fws_product.CATID 
webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_id
webits_product_has_kenmerken.kenmerk_value
```

every comparison with NULL will exclude the row from the reult